# How to automate mysql database creation on Node.js with nodemon?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, nodemon

I am working on a node.js app and I am using nodemon to run the script, which starts the server. My `package.json` file begins with something like this:

```
{
  "name": "file-converter-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A file format converter app",
  "main": "src/config/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/config/server.js",
    "test" : "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

My question is, is there a way apart from starting the `server.js` script to also call a script which would generate a database (lets say that it is called `files.sql`)? I wish to do sth like:

`"start": "nodemon src/config/server.js" && "files.sql"`

Does anyone know if this is possible and how I could proceed with it? I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by generate a database? Generate tables with columns ?

Comment: yeah. I mean having an sql script which has code like "CREATE DATABASE.." and let this script run from nodemos when the app starts

Comment: but for it you don't need bash script) Just create one sql file save it in you server. Then you can import it in docker for example https://github.com/bin-umar/TechnoparkDB/blob/master/Dockerfile#L25 or this answer maybe useful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276763/use-nodejs-to-run-an-sql-file-in-mysql